DAX - Count max consecutives days with events
I'd like to count the consecutives days in month / year.
My data looks like :

google sheet link
In this situation, I need to find :

Max consecutives days in may : 3
in june : 6
max total : 6
option : max consecutive in may for id_book B : 2

I created calculated columns to return 1 when this line is consecutive:

and

Any idea how should I tackle this problem ?
Thank you !

Try a Measure similar to:
Max Consecutive Days = 
  var tIsland = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
      DISTINCT('Stat lectures'),
      "island", DATEDIFF(
        RANK( DENSE, VALUES('Stat lectures'[date lecture]), ORDERBY('Stat lectures'[date lecture], ASC) ),
        'Stat lectures'[date lecture],
        DAY
      )
    )
  RETURN
    MAXX(
      GROUPBY( tIsland, [island], "rCount", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), 1) ),
      [rCount]
    )

var tIsland adds a new column based on the date's rank minus the date, meaning consecutive dates will share the same value.
RETURN then groups by this column and counts the number of rows etc...
This measure should give you the answer to all four of your scenarios above.
The above is based on Gap and Island analysis.

You need to calculate this as a measure (vs. calculated column), as the result need to be calculated on demand based on what is selected by the users, such as book ids, months.
Here is my solution:
Max Consecutive Days = 

// Find the date of the previous row for each row.
VAR __DatesWithPrevious =
    SUMMARIZE (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            'Stat lectures',
            "@PreviousDateLecture",
                OFFSET (
                    -1,
                    VALUES ( 'Stat lectures'[date lecture] ),
                    ORDERBY ( 'Stat lectures'[date lecture] )
                )
        ),
        'Stat lectures'[date lecture],
        [@PreviousDateLecture]
    )

// Retain only rows with consecutive dates.
VAR __FilteredConsecutiveDates =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER (
            __DatesWithPrevious,
            'Stat lectures'[date lecture] = [@PreviousDateLecture] + 1
        ),
        'Stat lectures'[date lecture]
    )

// Add rwo calculated columns:
// - @DaysFromEpoch: relative days from some reference date.
// - @Index: sequential row numbers within this table.
VAR __AddedRelativeDays =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        __FilteredConsecutiveDates,
        "@DaysFromEpoch",
        // Here I'm using Jan 1, 1970, which is the UNIX epoch, however any
        // fixed date will work just the same.
        DATEDIFF ( DATE ( 1970, 1, 1 ), 'Stat lectures'[date lecture], DAY ),
        "@Index",
        RANKX ( __FilteredConsecutiveDates, 'Stat lectures'[date lecture], , ASC )
    )

// Calculate unique numbers per each continuous dates.
VAR __AddedPartitionId =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( __AddedRelativeDays, "@PartitionId", [@DaysFromEpoch] - [@Index] )

// Count rows by each partition number. Adding 1 as the first date of each
// partition has been truncated.
VAR __TotalsByPartitions =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( __AddedPartitionId, [@PartitionId] ),
        "@ConsecutiveDays",
        VAR __CurrentId = [@PartitionId]
        RETURN SUMX ( __AddedPartitionId, IF ( [@PartitionId] = __CurrentId, 1 ) ) + 1
    )

// Calculate the longest continuity of dates.
VAR __MaxConsecutiveDays =
    MAXX ( __TotalsByPartitions, [@ConsecutiveDays] )

RETURN
    __MaxConsecutiveDays

Result:


you can try to create a column
Column = 
var _next=maxx(FILTER('Table','Table'[DATE LECTURE]=EARLIER('Table'[DATE LECTURE])+1),'Table'[DATE LECTURE])
var _next2=maxx(FILTER('Table','Table'[DATE LECTURE]=EARLIER('Table'[DATE LECTURE])+2),'Table'[DATE LECTURE])
var _last1=maxx(FILTER('Table','Table'[DATE LECTURE]=EARLIER('Table'[DATE LECTURE])-1),'Table'[DATE LECTURE])
var _last2=maxx(FILTER('Table','Table'[DATE LECTURE]=EARLIER('Table'[DATE LECTURE])-2),'Table'[DATE LECTURE])
return if(not(ISBLANK(_next))&&not(ISBLANK(_next2))&&month('Table'[DATE LECTURE])=month(_next)&&MONTH('Table'[DATE LECTURE])=month(_next2),1,if(not(ISBLANK(_last1))&&not(ISBLANK(_next))&&month('Table'[DATE LECTURE])=month(_next)&&MONTH('Table'[DATE LECTURE])=month(_last1),1,if(not(ISBLANK(_last1))&&not(ISBLANK(_last2))&&month('Table'[DATE LECTURE])=month(_last2)&&MONTH('Table'[DATE LECTURE])=month(_last1),1)))

screenshot
